# How to build simple sticky navigation with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to change the css of a div when scrolling. This is my code but unfortunately it won't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
            $('#subnav').css({
                'position' : 'fixed',
                'top' : '0'
            });
        } else {
            $('#subnav').css({
                'position' : 'static',
                'top' : 'auto'
            });
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: `'top' : 'none'` ?? That's not in the specs, use `'auto'` if you want the default value

Comment: Thanks, sry of course auto, changed that. But the whole thing doesn't work.

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jVmPR/

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get errors? Is there an element on your page with id "subnav"?

Comment: No errors and of course a div with id "subnav". barlasapaydin's solution worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

[**Here is working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4TfTF/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function() {
       var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
        if ( scrollVal > 150) {
            $('#subnav').css({'position':'fixed','top' :'0px'});
        } else {
            $('#subnav').css({'position':'static','top':'auto'});
        }
    });
 });
```

Note: If you have just one value you can use `else`, but if you have multiple values i suggest to not use `else`, because it creates conflict, use `else if` intead.

Comment: in long jquery plugins, it happens to me too. it is working on jsfiddle but same thing not working on my plugin ((: so i am trying to be more careful.

Comment: try this version http://jsfiddle.net/rBGsX/ which is _identical_ except that it _doesn't use a variable_.  **It works just the same!**

Comment: @Alnitak it is the same code what OP asked, it also works on me too but when it is inside a long function or with plugin usage, it starts to not work. Sorry can't prove it, but it happened to me too before. Bealive me i am really experienced with this issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971475/setting-css-value-limits-of-the-window-scrolling-animation/11971912#11971912

Comment: Whatever you're doing, it's either 1. a misunderstanding, 2. a bug in the code, or 3. a bug in the browser.  Semantically there is _no_ difference between `var a = expression; if (a)` and `if (expression)`

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah you are right, there is a bug in the code which i can't detect. I will be more carefull, next time. Thanks.