# jQuery: add classes according to image proportions

Tags: jquery

Hello,

I am trying to add classes to each image depending to its proportions (landscape/portrait/square). This code works in JSfiddle but not on the website (locally or on server):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('img').addClass('wide');
    $.each($('img'), function()
    {
        var image = $(this);

        if (image.height() > image.width()) {
            image.removeClass('wide');
            image.addClass('tall');
        } else if (image.height == image.width()) {
            image.removeClass('wide');
            image.addClass('square');
        }
    });
});​
```

Here is my JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LYxv6/ .

Comment: How does your sites HTML look like (post an excerpt).

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<script>

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9t0dwyu0P1qjfsubo1_500.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9iqv8oQl01qcpwsso1_500.jpg "/>
    <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9n4kyf8aA1r1thfzo5_1280.jpg"/>  
    

</body>
</html>

Comment: it works with the JSfiddle draft code. whats missing in my html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your code works on jsfiddle is because the site has (by default) wrapped your code in an `onload` handler.  This handler is called once all the images have loaded, unlike `$(document).ready()` which only waits until the DOM structure is complete.

The function to change the classes is trivial if you take advantage of the version of `addClass` that takes a function parameter instead of a string:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('img').addClass(function() {
        if (this.height === this.width) {
            return 'square';
        } else if (this.height > this.width) {
            return 'tall';
        } else {
            return 'wide';
        }
    });
});
```

In the callback `this` is the `<img>` element itself, and you can directly access its `.width` and `.height` properties without having to use jQuery.

This should be far more efficient than repeatedly calling jQuery functions inside a `.each()` loop.

Comment: Good answer mate, +1 from me.

Comment: works. can i simultaneously add a class to the img parrent div with this code? i tried injecting (this).parent().addClass("squarediv"); but that is not working.

Comment: `$(this.parentNode).addClass('squarediv')` _should_ work, but you'd need to put it before the relevant `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should run this script on

```
$(window).load()
```

...otherwise(on ready) it may happen that the images are not loaded yet and the size is still unknown when you access them.

You also forgot some parentheses here:

```
else if (image.height == image.width()) {
```

should be

```
else if (image.height() == image.width()) {
```

Comment: actually on an image tag he'd be better with just `this.width`.

Comment: would i still be needing the var image = $(this); when using this.width

Comment: Yes, because you still need `image` for addClass and removeClass

Comment: @Dr.Molle unless you use `.addClass(function() { ...})` per my answer

Comment: Please take a look at the original question, that's what my answer was intended for. The comments here are more about "optimizing" and are not related to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Changed to $('img').each and missing paranthesis at image.height() (this is a function)

```
$(window).load(function() {

$('img').addClass('wide');

$('img').each(function() {
    var image = $(this);

    if (image.height() > image.width()) {
        image.removeClass('wide');
        image.addClass('tall');
    }
    else if (image.height() == image.width()) {
        image.removeClass('wide');
        image.addClass('square');
    }

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use variables in `if` `else if` statements:

[**Here is jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/LYxv6/5/)

```
    var biggerVal = image.height() > image.width();
    var equalVal = image.height() == image.width();

    if ( biggerVal ) {
        image.removeClass('wide');
        image.addClass('tall');
    } else if ( equalVal ) {
        image.removeClass('wide');
        image.addClass('square');
    }
```

Same problem on this question: [How to build simple sticky navigation with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872381/scrolltop-and-then-div-fixed/11872508#11872508)

Comment: there's not _much_ point in this case declaring a variable that only gets used once...  In fact, you should be caching `.height()` and `.width()`, since those are both making function calls.

Comment: @Alnitak When i saw "*This code works in JSfiddle but not on the website (locally or on server):*" on the question, i suspect from not declaring variable because in long jQuery codes, this happened me before. Working on jsFiddle but same thing not working on site.

Comment: The main reason code tends to work on jsfiddle but not elsewhere is because jsfiddle _defaults_ to putting an 'onload' wrapper around your code, as is the case with the OP's fiddle.  Moving stuff into variables will have _absolutely nothing to do with it_!

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah you are right on this example, but it is always better to use variables in if else declarations in case not to create a jQuery conflict.

Comment: I have no idea what you think you're talking about.

Comment: @Alnitak Read the first comment please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872381/scrolltop-and-then-div-fixed/11872508#11872508

Comment: I can assure you that whatever fixed that code, putting that expression inside a variable was not it.

Comment: @Alnitak you are missing the point: **This occurs when it is inside a long jQuery function or used with some plugins. What i am talking about is not occurs because of document.ready or anythingelse because when defined var in if declaration, it starts to work.** It is like a conflict and this has really tiny chance to happen. I am sorry i can't prove it, but it happened me once. **Thanks for your interest.**

Answer (score 0):

On your server on local system, make an .html file.

Change it to document load, put in missing braces for one of the width parts - and make sure the .html file looks like the below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title></title>
    <script>
       $(document).load(function() {

    $('img').addClass('wide');

    $.each($('img'), function() {
        var image = $(this);

        if (image.height() > image.width()) {
            image.removeClass('wide');
            image.addClass('tall');
        }
        else if (image.height() == image.width()) {
            image.removeClass('wide');
            image.addClass('square');
        }

    });

});​
    </script>
    <style>
    img{
height:250px;
}
.wide{
border:10px solid #aed;

}
.tall{
border:10px dashed #dea;

}
.square{
border:10px dotted #ade;

}​
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9t0dwyu0P1qjfsubo1_500.jpg"/>
    <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9iqv8oQl01qcpwsso1_500.jpg "/>
    <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m9n4kyf8aA1r1thfzo5_1280.jpg"/>  
    </body>
    </html>
​
```

You may replace `<style></style>` and `<script></script>` with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourstyle.css"/>` and `<script type ="text/javascript" src="jquerywhatever.js"></script><script type ="text/javascript" src="YOURSCRIPT.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.proportions = function (options) {
        options = $.extend(options, {
            wideClass : 'wide',
            tallClass : 'tall',
            squareClass : 'square'
        });
        addProportions = function () {
            img = $(this);
            var ratio = img.width() / img.height();
            if (ratio > 1) {
                return img.addClass(options.wideClass);
            }
            if (ratio === 1) {
                return img.addClass(options.squareClass);
            }
            return img.addClass(options.tallClass);
        };
        return this.each(function () {
            if ($(this).width() !== undefined) {
                addProportions.call(this);
            } else {
                $(this).on('load', addProportions);
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));

jQuery(function ($) {
    jQuery('img').proportions();
});​
```

Putting it in a plugin makes it re-usable. And instead of using window.load as jsfiddle is doing, I've attached the function to each image's load event, so that the class is added immediately.