# How do I create a header that rolls into a sticky nav bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a header that contains graphics/images and when the user scrolls down to view the page content, the header starts off at the base and then becomes fixed at the top of the screen.

Here is an example: http://www.thinkful.com/learn/javascript-best-practices-1/

How would I create this?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results.

Comment: i've looked on google and haven't found any tutorials. I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: @Jay - Googling *"How do I create a header that rolls into a sticky nav bar?"* brings up at least three step-by-step tutorials and one stackoverflow question.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. Also, I suggest that you check the "related" sidebar on this page.

Comment: NO idea where I was looking. I made a big mistake, thank you.

Comment: @Jay - no problem, I'd recommend taking a look at this one in particular: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorials/create-a-sticky-navigation-header-using-jquery-waypoints/ - it uses the waypoints plugin mentioned in an answer.

Comment: @Joe Perfect, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used jQuery Waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) with a lot of success.

Answer (score 2):

By checking `scrollTop()`. You could easily have searched for this. [How to build simple sticky navigation with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872381/scrolltop-and-then-div-fixed)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

1. With `$(window).on('scroll',function(){ /*your code*/ });` you can
   bind a function to the scroll event.
2. Inside that function use `document.scrollTop` to know the current
   vertical position of the scroll bar
3. Change the css of the header and the side menu with `.css()` or `.addClass()`
4. Finally with the [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) you can change the URL
   without loading the page using the `history.replaceState()` method.

I've just forked a plugin called Scrollit.js that does the job. The [original version from Chris Polis](https://github.com/cmpolis/scrollIt.js) works great but doesn't change the URL. [My version](https://github.com/rbto/scrollIt.js) does change the URL has't been completely tested.